# An elevator accelerating upward, tension increases in the rope to which a fish hangs inside the elevator why?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

A fish is hanging in an elevator through a rope, when elevator accelerates upward the tension in the rope increases why? When elevator accelerates downward the tension in the rope decreases why?

Answer (score 1):

The tension in the rope is an effect of the force of gravity on the fish; the rope applies an upward acceleration to the fish (cancelling the downward acceleration due to gravity) and hence the tension.

A higher force pulling on the rope results in a higher tension, for example if the elevator were on a more massive planet with a higher gravity, or if someone stood below the fish and pulled downward on it. Another such source of pulling force is if rather than the fish being accelerated downward, the elevator were accelerated upward. From the point of view of the rope it doesn't matter which is happening; it's being pulled tighter either way.

Note that this only applies while the elevator is *accelerating* upward. If the elevator stops accelerating and travels at a constant speed upward, the tension returns to the value it held while the elevator was stationary.

Comment: i rode an elevator once that when it slowed to a stop after going up we all lifted up off the floor.  in an airplane ride through a thunderstorm we once hit a downdraft that splashed my drink on the ceiling ... good that i was belted in

Comment: when the elevator goes down and slows to a stop then the tension will increase

Answer (score 0):

Let $m$ be the mass of the fish, $T$ the tension in the rope and $a$ elevator's acceleration.When the elevator is not acceleration, $T=mg$. We chose the reference system to the earth. The fish accelerates with the elevator. Downwards: We write Newton's second law. $mg-T=ma$ so $T=m(g-a)$ and it is less than $mg$. Upwards: We write Newton's second law. $T-mg=ma$ so $T=m(g+a)$ and it is larger than $mg$. If we chose the refrence system to the elevator, we must use inertial forces.

Comment: Use math notation for readability. See http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation Just relpace `**...**` with `$...$` to beging with.

Answer (score 0):

The fish has a mass bigger than 0. This is why it wants to stay where it is. But the elevator moves and they are both connected by the rope.

You can try this in a thought (or tough) experiment:

1. Grab the hair on your head with your hand.
2. Now pull as hard and as fast as you can.